# Google Analytics not tracking any data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I've verified Google Analytics with the HTML option, inserted the tracking code on the page I'd like to track with this code:

```
    <script>
           (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
           (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
           m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

                  ga('create', 'UA-88853125-2', 'auto');
                  ga('send', 'pageview');

     </script>
```

However, it's not tracking anything. I had this problem for a few days now and tried different ways but can't seem to be able to figure it out. For more code,this is the website I'd like to track:

[website](http://cheappockets.com)

Comment: you have a missing library:
'NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://cheappockets.com/js/jquery.parallax-scroll.min.js'

Comment: Remove `<!--[if lt IE 9]>     <![endif]-->`on your html head

Comment: I've corrected the above but it's still not tracking? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any tracking at all, at least on the link you provided. I checked the page source as well and also with GA Tag Assistant. How did you include the tracking snippet? Was it through a plugin or something?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is following these steps from Google:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080

If one method is not working, you should try the other options as well.
Use this to test if the tracking is already working:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083